# Lines to Polygons problem qgis 2.14.9

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2.6, qgis-2.14

Recently I upgraded my qgis from 2.6.1 to 2.14.9. In the old version I used the tool 'polygonize' (not the plugin!) to transform lines into polygons. The results were always very good. Sadly, this tool no longer exists in the 2.14 version. Instead there is the 'lines to polygons' tool. However, this new tool does not seem to work properly. I did some tests with line layers which I had succesfully transformed into polygons in v2.6 but in the new version I do not get the same result! See the difference in results below:

[image]

I did some research and I see that more people are struggling with the lines to polygons tool. Is there a way to get the old polygonize tool back or is this problem resolved in more recent versions of QGIS?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [QGIS 2.14.6 Processing Extension, 'Polygonize' Tool missing](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210684/qgis-2-14-6-processing-extension-polygonize-tool-missing)

Comment: I definitely have it in 2.18.0, but it is in the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Thank you for the link Joseph. I installed 2.18.1 and I cannot find the polygonize tool as you said Vesanto (do you mean the GDAL conversion? Because that is not what I am refering to). So apparantly the working tool 'polygonize' has been removed in recent versions and replaced by a tool that is not functioning? And apparantly, this problem has been around since 2.14...

Comment: You have to remove the processing plugin from `username\.qgis2\python\plugins\ ` because it conflicts with the current plugin now being a core function. See the linked question about details on that. And the Polygonize tool has got some strage translations, e.g. in French it is `Mise en Polygones`.

Comment: Thank you Andre for your comment. I read the linked question thread but it does not provide me with an answer. I do not have a processing folder under username\...\plugins\ . I do have a processing folder under C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\ but deleting that does not solve my problem. The 'line to polygon' tool still does not function and I also have no option of using the old 'polygonize' tool. Btw; I use an english version of qgis, so the tool is not under some weird foreign name.

Comment: @Frank Check in C:\Users\USERNAME\.qgis2  it is a hidden folder.