# QGIS attribute table displaying wrong features?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In QGIS 2.18.1 I set up Attribute table to 'Show features Visible On Map' but in the form view in the list are definitely more features than visible in the map.

In the screenshot below two features are visible in the map (Layer Road_Erlangen_2016_10_10):

1. The orange one on the top right corner and
2. The (selected) yellow one in the middle

... but the screenshot reveals 5 (when I scroll down ~15) feature in the left hand list:

[image]

In another case I have too few features in the list (4 in the map, one in the list):

[image]

My first thought was that the slow reacting WMS basemap aerial photo layer makes such problems, but turning it off changes nothing.

Data source is a shapefile, I created a spatial index under Layer properties and I'm in editing mode (where leaving editing mode changes nothing). Even 'Reload the table' button has no effect.

Am I missing some settings or what may be my problem?

Comment: Where on the map are the extra features which are visible in the attribute table?

Comment: far, far, away... about 10 x map canvas width. But two other observations: The shapefile had no id column, I added one and I'm currently working with that dataset on another machine, on wich I am unable to reproduce the behaviour. Strange... I'll try the dataset with id column on my other machine later and report my observations.

Comment: something totally weird with my installation, same behaviour no matter id column or not. Tried to remove qgis completely from my machine and reinstall, no success. probably somehow related to my corrupt installation: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210684/qgis-2-14-6-processing-extension-polygonize-tool-missing wich i still observe.

Comment: Did you find the behaviour worse when in edit mode (a couple of years later... your memory may not extend that far)?  I've been having issues that the wrong feature information is displayed for a selected feature when in edit mode. When I switch out, it seems to come back to the correct information.