# Cannot select SHP format as saved format after merge two layers QGIS 2.16 and 2.18

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, merge

I was using 2.16 version and everything was alright, I could merge two layers via Vector - Data Management - Merge and use .shp format as saved output format. Unfortunately my working laptop was reinstalled and now when I installed same QGIS back - I can't use this .shp option (I have only dbf, csv, xlsx and ods) and it really drives me crazy. I removed 2.16 and replaced with 2.18 but still have same issue. I 2.16 I could at least use SAGA merge tools for it but in 2.18 I can't.

I am trying to merge and save two layers (shp with same geometry type and CRS).

Add: I tried to download QGIS 2.18.4, removed all registry files and every single file related to QGIS to make sure I don' t have any hidden setting in Windows folders but it didn't help.

I looked into all QGIS Settings I found and I just can't see anything related to it.

Tried Vector menu, Processing Toolbox and nothing.

[image: Saved file drop down menu]

Comment: When you say cannot select, you mean the physical file exists but you cannot select it in QGIS ? Did you try to open the file in QGIS separately ?

Comment: I have shapefile and I can select layers for Merge but I can' t save them as shp.

Comment: it may be a permission issue, may be the folder where u r saving shape file is protected, either try to save in different place or try to open QGIS as Administrator and save the file.

Comment: Same issue when you use the 'merge vector layers' under QGIS geoalgorithms|Vector general tools, or when you try to save it from the layer tree (cp. my updated answer below)?

Comment: You installed it from the installer downloaded from the website, not via osgeo4w installer?

Comment: It is not permission issue as I have admin rights for my laptop and can do anything, tried Run as Administrator and it didnt help. I tried every possible option for merge and still the same. After reinstall my laptop I had 2.16 version again due to recovery, now using 2.18 downloaded from website (didn' t work in both version). Please have a look on my comment below in 2nd answer. It really drives me crazy. I don' t want to import every single shp again and set up all settings :(

Comment: Couple of month ago I had a strange issue, where things could not be found as expected: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210684/qgis-2-14-6-processing-extension-polygonize-tool-missing. Neither Installer from the QGIS site nor 'Advanced Install' from OSGeo4W installer (my usual way) solved the problem. The only thing that helped was uninstall and remove everything QGIS I found in the registry, and then reinstall via OSGeo4W Installer, 'Express Desktop Install'. Perhaps worth a try in your case also. Cp. https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: Hmm... Thats interesting approach, never thought about that. I did clean all registry and anything with QGIS name on it from my laptop, but I always used classic website .exe download as I never had problem with it.

Comment: Just tried and nothing again. When I open my project I can' t use save as shp option. When I import requested shp layers to new project I can save it as a shp. It is really a big mystery for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the `merge` tool from the processing toolbox. Activate the processing toolbox via Processing>Toolbox `(Ctl-Alt-T)` and search for 'merge'. In this tool you are not only restricted to two shapefiles, but you may  select n from the loaded layers and merge them together:

[image]

The resulting merged vector can be saved as a shape file in various ways:

1) directly from the processing tool: click the three dotted button right beside `[Save to temporary file]`, in the 'save as' dialogue from the combo select the file format you wish:

[image]

[image]

2) You may wish to preview your result before saving it. In this case, leave the `[Save to temporary file]` as it is, preview your result, and if it's ok, right click it in the Layer tree and select 'Save As...'. In the next dialogue you can select the file format you prefer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited my question as I didnt ask correctly. My issue is for saving merged layers. I don' t have .shp format as an option there.

Comment: Ok... in that case I'll extend my answer as well ;-)

Comment: Thats exactly my problem... I don' t have .shp format there as an option for saving. Before Windows reinstall I always used this tool in same way and there was .shp ... :(

Comment: Ok. I found something. If I create new project and import same two shp (both points, same CRS) - as I tried to save before ... I have .shp as option for saving... But when I want to do it in my original Project I can' t save it as a shp again. I thought it is due different version of QGIS now, but my project was created in 2.16 version and after Windows reinstall I had 2.16. version again... I really don't understand.